# Visual Studio 2010 outline text with color

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-7, text

I'm creating a basic app in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 for Windows Phone 7.1. I can't seem to find out how to add an outline around my text. I have an image as the background and any colour I put onto it doesn't look right. So I want basic white text with a black outline for a title but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Does anyone know how I can add an outline to the text, do I have to do it in XAML code or in C# or is there a way to do it using the Visual Studio GUI?

**EDIT**: I just decided to create the images in photoshop and delete the background so the title looks like its just text although its an image. Makes it harder to edit if I need to but not too much trouble. Thank you to the people who tried to help.

Comment: Is the text static or dynamic?  If static, consider adding it as a path in your XAML

Comment: Also, are you trying to do this at `runtime` on the Windows 7 device or are you just wanting some static `artwork` to ship with your app.

Comment: Static artwork i think, its just a basic title for the page, nothing fancy. I suppose i could probably just create the tile in photoshop and delete the background but then my title would be a picture rather than just text which isn't really ideal.

Comment: Thanks Mark, then probably the easiest thing to do is use a paint program such as the one mentioned by Nevra below or add the text to say Adobe Illustrator; export the path and import into your XAML where you can stroke it with any width pen.  I'd post the answer but it was years ago and I forget sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use Paint.Net Outline Pack, try from [here](http://paint.net.amihotornot.com.au/Download/PluginsPack/).

or try this,

```
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath;

GraphicsPath p = new GraphicsPath(); 
p.AddString(
    "Your Text",
    new Point(0, 0),             
    );
g.DrawPath(Pens.Color, p);
```

Comment: It says that there is no such thing as system.drawing and i cant download anything as I'm in college. Do you know of any other way? Thanks for your help

Comment: That WinForms code won't work on a Windows 7 phone but it will work superbly for generating static artwork ahead of time